# Script Executions in web hosting server exceeding maximum allot time

Tags: php, jquery, web-hosting, slim-3

I have a website written in PHP and jQuery. The website uses an API developed using slim framework to perform data saving and retrieval operations.

Of late the server has been showing gateway timeout quite frequently and when consulted with the hosting provider, they told me the api script has be huge execution count and it needs to be check.

I use AJAX method in jQuery to fetch JSON data from the API I created using Slim.
Could any learned progammer tell me whether each $.ajax() call to a API method (either get or post) is treated as script execution count?

My current javascript file in website has around 100 $.ajax() calls to custom post methods written in slim framework API file.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Uh, any request to a php file would be considered an execution of that php script.  Whither from ajax or normal browsing.  You access that script, and it has to run in order to know how to generate the response to the client.

Comment: Thanks Taplar for the quick info. My current script execution count is exceeding 2000 per hour and this is the main reason why hosting provider has block script execution. I guess many of the world's popular webapps having thousands even millions of users are also relying on PHP. Do it mean we need to upgrade hosting plan?

Comment: On average for that 2000 per hour, how many users is that?  I would say the first step would be to evaluate how many of those requests are per user.  See if any of them are duplicate requests that are not necessary and that could be cached for some period of time.

Comment: Sorry for joining late. On an average there are about 200-300 active users per day. Most of their activities include adding records of their business contacts, searching existing records, sending email from the app etc.